# How to add element at Last index Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsmutablearray, swift2

I am getting an Array from server and I store it in NSMutableArray. Now the issue is that the Array is not sorted. For eg. array = ["A","B","None","C","D"]. I want to sort it and place the "None" element at last. i.e ["A","B","C","D","None"]. Tried swapping but was unable to match the condition, as the array may increase in future. Check my code below which is not working as expected.

```
if array.containsObject( "None" ){
        print("\(array.indexOfObject("None"))")
        let noneIndex = array.indexOfObject("None")
        print(noneIndex)
        array.removeObject(noneIndex)
        print("Remove Array:-\(array)")
        array.insertObject(noneIndex, atIndex: (array.lastObject?.index)!)
        print("Sorted Array:-\(array)")
    }
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't use the provided `sort()` or `sorted()` methods?

Comment: You just need array.addobject("None")

Comment: Why `NSMutableArray` and not a Swift array `[String]` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding what it is that you need to do, but you could use `sorted()` on your array if you just want to sort it alphabetically.

You could also use `filter` to remove "None" from your array, sort it, and then append "None" as the last element

For instance, if you have

```
let elements = ["Alpha", "Bold", "None", "charlie", "Delta", "echo", "zebra", "k"]
```

You could start out by filtering it:

```
let filteredElements = elements.filter { $0.uppercased() != "NONE"}
```

Sort the filtered elements:

```
var sortedElements = filteredElements.sorted { $0.uppercased() < $1.uppercased()}
```

Append "None"

```
sortedElements.append("None") // ["Alpha", "Bold", "charlie", "Delta", "echo", "k", "zebra", "None"]
```

And be done.

Here it is combined:

```
let lastElement = "None"
let elements = ["Alpha", "Bold", "None", "charlie", "Delta", "echo", "zebra", "k"]
var sortedElements = elements.filter({$0.uppercased() != lastElement.uppercased()}).sorted(by: {$0.uppercased() < $1.uppercased()})
sortedElements.append(lastElement)
```

Hope that helps you.

Comment: Its not just alphabets , it can be anything , like words, . Condition is "None" should be last everytime.

Comment: @iDeveloper, in `sorted` closure add condition that makes `"None"` always greatest value.

Comment: @pbodsk this is not working, it says, Value of type 'Elememt'(Aka 'AnyObject') has no member 'uppercased'

Comment: Hmm, OK, that must be because your array is defined as containing `AnyObject` objects instead of `String`s. How is your array defined?

Comment: And as @jpetric says in a comment to his answer, you should consider using a Swift array instead of `NSMutableArray`. You get the `filter`, `map` and `sorted` methods amongst other goodies :)

Comment: @pbodsk as per your suggestion I have used NSArray still it says Value of type 'Elememt'(Aka 'AnyObject') has no member 'uppercased'

Comment: @iDeveloper sorry, then you have must misunderstood me, I meant Array, not NSArray but just Array. But...that is another situation. Your problem right now is that your array contains `AnyObject` elements, meaning that they can be anything. `uppercased()` on the other hand is a method on `String` objects, so when you try to say `uppercased()` on your elements, then the compiler doesn't know what type the elements are, you've told it that they are `AnyObject` so that is all it knows, and therefore it gets confused when you try to call `uppercased()` on `AnyObject` elements.

Comment: so...it would be interesting to see how your array is actually declared :)

Comment: var array  =  NSArray () while declaring and in viewDidLoad self.array = []

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130676/discussion-between-pbodsk-and-ideveloper).

Answer (score 1):

```
var array = ["A", "B", "None", "C", "D"]
if let noneIndex = array.index(of: "None") {
    array.remove(at: noneIndex)
    array.append("None")
}
print(array)
```

Comment: Note that you don't need the check  `if array.contains()` if you write  `if let noneIndex = array.indexOf("None") {`

Answer (score 1):

This should move `None` at the end of the array, and sort the other elements:

```
let ["A", "B", "None", "C", "D"]
array.sorted { $1 == "None" || $0 < $1 } // ["A", "B", "C", "D", "None"]
```

This simply takes benefits of the `by` argument that can be passed to the `sort`/`sorted` method from `Array`.

**Edit** @MartinR had a very strong point regarding the comparison predicate from this answer, which indeed doesn't offer a `strong weak ordering`. Sorting the array with a correct predicate would be along the lines of:

```
array.sorted { $0 == "None" ? false : $1 == "None" ? true : $0 < $1 }
```

Comment: @MartinR thanks for the observation, corrected the code

Comment: That might work, but now the comparator is not a "strict weak ordering" as required: `"None" < "None"`

Comment: @MartinR, correct, instances of "None" will be moved around due to the fact that `"None" < "None"`. We can be pedantic and address this, we gain a little speed, however with the cost of increasing the complexity of the closure.

Comment: I don't think this is unnecessary pedantry. The `sorted` methods *requires* a strict weak ordering. If that prerequisite is not satisfied the behaviour is undefined.

Comment: @MartinR, hmm... I missed the `strict weak ordering` part from the API docs, thanks for bringing that up. I updated the answer, hopefully now is a correct one :)

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
// starting test array
let array = ["B", "None", "C","P","None","A", "Q"]
var sorted = array.sorted { (str1, str2) -> Bool in
    return str1 < str2
}

sorted.forEach { str in
    if str == "None" {
        if let idx = sorted.index(of: str) {
            sorted.remove(at: idx)
            sorted.append(str)
        }
    }
}

// Sorted array is now ["A", "B", "C", "P", "Q", "None", "None"]
```

Comment: I would suggest using Swift's array. It will be better in the long run.

Comment: Sorted is not available in swit 3.

Comment: You sure? Because I tried the example in Playground with Swift 3. If you copy this whole example in Playground it should work.

Comment: XCode 8.1 Swift 3

Comment: There should be `array.sorted` method in swift 3.